# Docker: "go.mod file not found" when it clearly exists

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to make a fullstack app that uses a go backend and a nextjs frontend (which I haven't created yet). I was following a tutorial for making the backend and everything was working fine so far. However, I wanted to move the backend stuff into its own folder so I could keep it and the frontend separate. Now, whenever I run `docker compose build` it completes with no errors, but when I run `docker compose up`, this is what I get (I'm using air to have hot reload functionality):

```
goapp-1  | watching .
goapp-1  | watching backend
goapp-1  | watching backend/cmd
goapp-1  | watching backend/cmd/database
goapp-1  | watching backend/cmd/handlers
goapp-1  | watching backend/cmd/models
goapp-1  | watching backend/tmp
goapp-1  | !exclude tmp
goapp-1  | building...
goapp-1  | go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
goapp-1  | failed to build, error: exit status 1
```

However, when I go into Docker desktop and run `ls` in that image, it shows that `go.mod` is right there!

[image]

So what's the issue?

I've tried changing the target directories and contexts in `compose.yaml` and my dockerfile, all to no success. Running `go build` instead of `air` gives me the same error as well.

Here's my file tree:

```
databeis2
 ┣ .vscode
 ┃ ┗ settings.json
 ┣ backend
 ┃ ┣ cmd
 ┃ ┃ ┣ ...
 ┃ ┃ ┣ main.go
 ┃ ┃ ┗ routes.go
 ┃ ┣ tmp
 ┃ ┃ ┣ build-errors.log
 ┃ ┃ ┗ main
 ┃ ┣ .air.toml
 ┃ ┣ Dockerfile
 ┃ ┣ go.mod
 ┃ ┣ go.sum
 ┃ ┗ pre_cmd.txt
 ┣ tmp
 ┃ ┗ build-errors.log
 ┣ .env
 ┗ compose.yaml
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.21

WORKDIR /app

RUN go install github.com/cosmtrek/air@latest

COPY . .
RUN go mod tidy
```

And compose.yaml:

```yaml
services:
  goapp:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: air ./cmd/main.go -b 0.0.0.0
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres-db:
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!!

Comment: Looks like `air` is running in `backend`'s parent directory

Comment: Does this issue happen without using air? If not, then an [mcve] would include the commands executed and configuration files used to run air.

Comment: Can you run `air`, `go build`, _etc._ directly on the host for day-to-day development; and `go build` a binary in your image that you'd use, without live rebuilding, for integration testing and deployment?

Comment: Yes, the issue happens without air when I run `go build ./cmd/main.go -b 0.0.0.0`. I'm using the default settings for air though, except I changed `cmd` like so: ` cmd = "go build -o ./tmp/main ./backend"`

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm sorry but I have no idea what that means, I'm super new to docker stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! The issue was I needed to change my `WORKDIR` to `backend` after copying the files in my dockerfile.

```
FROM golang:1.21

WORKDIR /app

RUN go install github.com/cosmtrek/air@latest

COPY . .
# Add the below line 
WORKDIR /app/backend

RUN go mod tidy
```